# Avoiding label bubbles overlapping horizontal line segments in TimelinePlot

Tags: plotting, spacing

I am creating a very large TimelinePlot, with perhaps six times the number of entries as in this near-minimal example (code below):

[image: TimelinePlot]

Notice that bubble (labels) for the entries *below* the horizontal axis are all below the horizontal line segments.  As such, these bubbles never obscure the horizontal lines and their ranges.  Good.  The same cannot be said for the label bubbles *above* the horizontal axis.  As you can see the bubble for *Frederic Remington* obscures the end of the black horizontal segment for *Katsushika Hokusai*.  This problem is far more severe in my full TimelinePlot (with many more entries).

I've tried changing `Spacings` but that merely adjusts the vertical spacings, and does not prevent the unwanted line overlap.

How can I force all the bubbles above the axis so they do not obscure the horizontal timeline segments?

---

```
tlp = TimelinePlot[
   {

    <|{Entity["Person", "LeonardoDaVinci::47w36"] -> 
       Interval[{"1452", "1521"}],
      Entity["Person", "GiovanniBellini::f5m7r"] -> 
       Interval[{"1430", "1516"}],
      "Giovanni Antonio Boltraffio" -> Interval[{"1466", "1516"}],
      "Bernardio Luini" -> Interval[{"1481", "1532"}],
      "Cesare da Sesto" -> Interval[{"1477", "1523"}],
      "Andrea del Verrocchio" -> Interval[{"1435", "1488"}],
      "Paolo Veronese" -> Interval[{"1528", "1588"}]

      }|>,

    <|{Entity["Person", "CamilleCorot::vx57d"] -> 
       Interval[{"1796", "1875"}],
      "Gustav Courbet" -> Interval[{"1819", "1877"}],
      Entity["Person", "HonoreDaumier::8868j"] -> 
       Interval[{"1808", "1879"}],
      Entity["Person", "GustaveCaillebotte::7tgk6"] -> 
       Interval[{"1848", "1894"}]
      }|>,

    <|{Entity["Person", "JosefAlbers::6j228"] -> 
       Interval[{"1888", "1976"}],
      Entity["Person", "WinslowHomer::zyp3z"] -> 
       Interval[{"1836", "1910"}],
      Entity["Person", "FredericRemington::c9p55"] -> 
       Interval[{"1861", "1909"}],
      "Thomas Eakins" -> Interval[{"1844", "1916"}],
      Entity["Person", "ChuckClose::84btx"] -> 
       Interval[{"1940", "2030"}]
      }|>,

    <|{Entity["Person", "ThomasGainsborough::4sjkp"] -> 
       Interval[{"1727", "1788"}],
      "Joseph Wright of Derby" -> Interval[{"1734", "1797"}],
      Entity["Person", "Banksy::72t76"] -> 
       Interval[{"1975", "2030"}],
      Entity["Person", "DavidHockney::k88k8"] -> 
       Interval[{"1937", "2030"}]
      }|>, 

    <|{Entity["Person", "JanDavidszDeHeem::2gt75"] -> 
       Interval[{"1606", "1684"}],
      Entity["Person", "FransHals::c2f7f"] -> 
       Interval[{"1582", "1666"}],
      Entity["Person", "GerritVanHonthorst::9387f"] -> 
       Interval[{"1592", "1656"}],
      "Loyset Liédet" -> Interval[{"1420", "1484"}],
      Entity["Person", "MCEscher::pvv7b"] -> Interval[{"1898", "1972"}]
      }|>,

    <|{Entity["Person", "PabloPicasso::k6djr"] -> 
       Interval[{"1881", "1973"}],
      Entity["Person", "DiegoVelazquez::jk6k2"] -> 
       Interval[{"1599", "1660"}]
      }|>,

    <|{Entity["Person", 
        "HansMemling::q4f6g"] Interval[{"1430", "1494"}],
      Entity["Person", "AlbrechtDurer::qxh64"] -> 
       Interval[{"1471", "1528"}],
      Entity["Person", "GustavKlimt::fssw3"] -> 
       Interval[{"1862", "1918"}]
      }|>,

    <|{"Katsushika Hokusai" -> Interval[{"1760", "1849"}]
      }|>

    },

   PlotRange -> {"1360", "2003"},
   TicksStyle -> 
    Directive[{FontSize -> 14, Italic, Black, 
      FontFamily -> "Times"}],
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Orange, Darker[Yellow], Green, Blue, Purple, 
     Darker[Purple], Black},
   AspectRatio -> 1/2,
   PlotLayout -> "Packed",
   Spacings -> {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
   Background -> LightGray,
   ImageSize -> 1200,
   AxesOrigin -> Center];
tlp2 = Legended[tlp,
  Placed[LineLegend[{Red, Orange, Darker[Yellow], Green, Blue, Purple,
      Darker[Purple], 
     Black}, (Style[#, 16, Italic, 
        FontFamily -> "Times"] &) /@ {"Italian", "French", "American",
       "British", "Flemish", "Spanish", "German", "Japanese"}, 
    LegendLayout -> (Row[Row[#, Spacer[1]] & /@ #, Spacer[7]] &), 
    LegendMargins -> 0], Below]]
```

Comment: If you fix the typo (`->` is missing in `Entity["Person", 
        "HansMemling::q4f6g"] Interval[{"1430", "1494"}]`) in the next-to-last entry in the list of associations, the picture looks good.

Comment: Oh... thanks so much.  Again.

Comment: I would have expected `assoc = Association["a""b","c"->3]` to issue a warning message; it doesn't. We get the message "The argument Association[a b,c->3] is not a valid Association or a list of rules." when when we try to access any element of  `assoc`, say, `Values @assoc` or `Lookup["c"]@assoc`.